# Getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET randomly from aws

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I execute

```
POST http://ec2-34-193-48-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

I get

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

using laravel 5.5 I am getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` occasionally. 
But it works perfectly on my local server.

Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Especially that URL that you wrote down looks really suspicious. You want others to spend their time to help you, so **you** please spend the time to write up a clear question.